# unity3d with sqlite database plugins for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I'm building a simple 2D sidescroller game with unity 5.0 and sqlite database for android. I had my plugins from this link https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d and successfully built it for android. but the problem is it is not loading any database. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at CodeCoding [SQLite4Unity3d](https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d) Plugin. It basically contains everything you need for fast-forwarding integration of SQLite into Unity3D.

Comment: thanks men. It helps me alot.-

Comment: @KimBryanDimayugaLobrino Please mark my Answer as Accepted.